# Responsive Nav Horizontal to Stacked / Bootstrap 2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-2

Are there classes in Bootstrap 2.3.2 for a horizontal nav, which at a certain breakpoint, becomes stacked?

I'm trying to avoid switching out classes on the parent with javascript.

I've looked all through the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2), but no luck.

Thanks!